# How to do pagination on a Wordpress "Page"

Tags: wordpress

I have seen this function call `get_query_var('paged')` work in other places

my page is `/news/page/2`

But `get_query_var('paged')` is allways returning 0.

What gives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was I called `query_posts('posts_per_page=5');` that reset the query value of paged.

If I called `get_query_var('paged')` before `query_posts('posts_per_page=5');`  it works.